# What is the VIEW in a backend REST-API?

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, model-view-controller

sorry for that stupid question.

I want to create a simple REST-API (or maybe later in combination with GraphQL).
PS: I'm using C#.NET Core / .NET-5.0 and PostGreSQL. Working with Rider with an "empty solution".

| API-Controller | Models | Services | Repositories | *Database* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Request | InputModel | DataValidation, DataManipulation, IPO | DB-Entities | *SQL-Code* |
| Response | OutputModel | DataManipulation, DataValidation, IPO | DB-Entities | *SQL-Code* |

**So I have this structure (directories):**

- Controllers { ... }
- Models

  - Commons { ... }
  - Inputs { ... }
  - Entities { ... }
  - Outputs { ... }
- Services { ... }
- PgsqlRepository { ... }

In my mind, the VIEW of a REST API is the combination of the "end point" and the "output model".
Both are provided by the corresponding API controller.

**So where exactly is the VIEW in the MVC for a REST API?**
Or is a backend interface (with REST API) not a classic MVC at all?

And yes, the MVVM in the frontend naturally offers a VIEW and a ViewModel.
But my question is only about the backend.

Comment: Are you asking what the purpose of views is?

Comment: @RainbowDash: No, but everybody told me to use MVC to operate a REST API. Models and Controllers are known, but does a REST API has a View? 
It's - what I said - a combination of the "end point" (API) and the "output model" (Response). Isn't it?

Comment: Right, you don't need views if the response is JSON or XML.

Comment: In MVC, View is the user interface. ie UI. Here you your case you are working with only API. And API works with REQUEST, RESPONSE. In you case view is not need, all your api returns json or xml in response based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

there are different types of controller - having different functionalities -

An API controller can not return view instead of they return serialized data whereas an MVC controller can return a view.

if this is what you're seeking.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).